# Is there a way to delete all rows that belong to a group if one particular condition in the group is true?

Tags: dplyr

I have a unique identifier for each company, with observations for each company at different years. I need to figure out how to drop the companies' observations for each year if the amount exceeds a certain amount in a certain year (`signalledyear`).

Maybe something like this, not sure how to put this into code?

```
%>% group_by(id, year) %>% filter(amount > 10 when year = signalledyear)
```

Note, `signalledyear` is also a column in the dataframe.

Comment: I posted an answer, but unsure what exactly your data look like. Can you post some of your data via `dput`? You can enter `dput(head(df))` into the console, then paste the results into your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `any` to remove whole groups where any row meets the condition of `year` being equal to the `signalledyear` and the `amount` is less than 10.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  filter(!any(amount < 10 & year == signalledyear))
```

**Output**

```
     id  year signalledyear amount
  <dbl> <dbl>         <dbl>  <dbl>
1     1  2010          2011      5
2     1  2011          2011     14
3     1  2012          2011      5
4     1  2013          2011     12
5     1  2014          2011     12
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2), year = c(2010, 
2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013), signalledyear = c(2011, 
2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010), amount = c(5, 
14, 5, 12, 12, 6, 9, 12, 14)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))

#   id year signalledyear amount
# 1  1 2010          2011      5
# 2  1 2011          2011     14
# 3  1 2012          2011      5
# 4  1 2013          2011     12
# 5  1 2014          2011     12
# 6  2 2010          2010      6
# 7  2 2011          2010      9
# 8  2 2012          2010     12
# 9  2 2013          2010     14
```

Comment: Almost. Basically, in your example data, if you replaced the amount with 9 in row 6, which is less than 10, it would then drop all rows with id 2.

Comment: @r-learning-machine So, you want to drop all rows of an id if year equals signaled year and the amount is less than 10?

Comment: Yes that is exactly right

Comment: @r-learning-machine I have updated the answer to remove the whole group if any rows in a group meet the condition.